# confused with server instances

Tags: java, servlets

I have the following piece of code its working fine,no issues but i am confused,how to make more than one instances of this.Every time i run this i get "**there are 1 instances running"**

```
public class HolisticCounter extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static int classCount = 0;  // shared by all instances
  int count = 0;              // separate for each servlet
  static Hashtable instances = new Hashtable();  // also shared

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
                               throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    count++;
    out.println("Since loading, this servlet instance has been accessed " +
                count + " times.");

    // Keep track of the instance count by putting a reference to this
    // instance in a Hashtable. Duplicate entries are ignored. 
    // The size() method returns the number of unique instances stored.
    instances.put(this, this);
    out.println("There are currently " + 
                instances.size() + " instances.");

    classCount++;
    out.println("Across all instances, this servlet class has been " +
                "accessed " + classCount + " times.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Try making concurrent requests.

Comment: It is fine. Why would you have more than one instance of a servlet? Concurrent requests will run same servlet in concurrent threads.

Comment: Just for knowledge. Can u tell me how to do it?

Comment: Actually the tutorial where i read it from,showed the output that "there are 2 instances running" so i was curious how to get 2 instances running

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, there is only ever one servlet instance per `<servlet>` entry. The container does not need to instantiate any more, and so it reuses the same instance for every request.

The server is *permitted* to instantiate several, but there's usually no reason for it to do so.

Comment: thanks for the answer but can u tell me how to create another instance?

Comment: @raghav: Why would you want to?

Comment: Actually the tutorial where i read it from,showed the output that "there are 2 instances running" so i was curious how to get 2 instances running .

Comment: @raghav: I suggest ignoring that tutorial; it's either out of date or just plain wrong.